# I want to make one! VAR that go from 10 to 10 to arrive at 60 then back to 00

Tags: var

I want to make one `!VAR` that go from `10` to `10` to arrive at `60` then back to `00`.

Example: `0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 | 0, 10, 20, 30`

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var num = 0, while(num<=60){document.write (num + " ");num = num + 10;}")

script Imacros
```

sorry my bad English

Comment: Please tag the question with the *language* you are using. Otherwise the chance that you get help is quite low.

Comment: So...something like a loop offset with a modulo of 61?

Comment: @FelixKling The part in quotes looks like JavaScript maybe... Dunno about the other stuff OP, please fill us in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you want, but if it is C like, then `%` will do what you want.

```
 SET !VAR1 EVAL("var num = 0, while(num<=60){var x = (num + 10) % 60; document.write (x+ " ");num = num + 10;}")

script Imacros
```

Comment: My language is Portuguese BR
the script is imacros for firefox
I do not know what language it uses.

Comment: Mark Lakata your script dont work                                                       SyntaxError: wrong format of SET command, line: 4 (Error code: -910)